# Alternative to Sign

Tags: functions

The `Sign` function works in a very straightforward manner:

```
Sign[8]
Sign[-8]
Sign[0]
```

> ```
> 1
> -1
> 0
> ```

Unfortunately, in my code I need `Sign[0]` to equal 1 or negative 1. I tried this but get a funny error:

```
ssign[x_] := Sign[2*(Boole[NonNegative[x]] - 0.5)]
Plot[ssign[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

> Plot::exclul: {NonNegative[x] - 0, (-0.5 + Re[Boole[NonNegative[x]]]) - 0} must be a list of equalities or real-valued functions. >>

Then, I tried a bunch of things, and this seemed like the best:

```
ssign[x_] := 2 UnitStep[x] - 1
Plot[ssign[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

I am not too happy with this solution; there is still a zero coming out, just not at `ssign[0]`. Any ideas how to improve it?

Comment: At which `x` is `2 UnitStep[x] - 1` zero?  I don't think there is one.  It seems the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to define your `ssign` function is:

```
ssign[0 | 0.]= 1;
ssign[x_] := Sign[x]

Plot[ssign[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 4):

Define your own:

```
mysign[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x >= 0}, {-1, True}}]

mysign[-2]  (* Out: -1 *)
mysign[2]   (* Out:  1 *)
mysign[0]   (* Out:  1 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the `UnitStep` function defined by the OP is a perfectly good solution to this problem, but I thought I'd point out another option,

```
Unprotect[Sign];
Sign[0] = 1;
Protect[Sign];
Sign /@ {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}
(* {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Of course you have to be careful when modifying the definition of low-level built in functions, but, just as important, sometimes you have to live a little and take a few risks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own `sign`. If you want Sign[0] to be randomly 1 or -1,

```
sign[x_] := If[Sign[x] == 0, RandomChoice[{-1, 1}], Sign[x]]
{sign[8], sign[-8], sign[0], sign[0], sign[0]}
{1, -1, 1, -1, -1}
```

though you could just choose one of the two.

Answer (score 2):

```
sign[n_] := 2 Boole[10^10 n > RandomChoice[{1, -1}]] - 1
```

or using the same idea,

```
sign[n_] := Sign[10^10 n + RandomChoice[{1, -1}]]

sign[0] (*1*)
sign[0] (*-1*)
sign[-2] (*-1*)
```

unless $\left|n\right|<10^{^-10}$.

---

**EDIT**

I thought that you wanted the function to randomly choose -1 or 1 for 0. If one of these is fine, this is an even simpler way:

```
sign[n_] := 2 Boole[n >= 0] - 1
```